# managing video watch history of users in cassandra

Tags: mysql, cassandra, datastax, cassandra-4.0

I was using MYSQL database but one of my history table growing very fast already more than 300 Million rows which making database slow and difficult to create backups. So i decided move just that table in Cassandra. It's my first time on Cassandra. In mysql I'm storing user_id, video_id, watch_secs, watch_counter, timestamp, user_id,video_id is unique composite key and increment watch_secs and watcher_counter if already exists. I tried to do following with Cassandra

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS history
(
    user_id int,
    video_id int,
    watch_secs int,
    watch_counter int,
    last_updated timestamp,
    history_timestamp timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY ((user_id, video_id))
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS history_counter
(
    user_id int,
    video_id int,
    watch_secs counter,
    watch_counter counter,
    PRIMARY KEY ((user_id, video_id))
);
```

I have created two tables for incrementing seconds and counter and other table same data with timestamps because limitations due to counter.

Now that is working good for storing data but here i have two issues deleting and getting data.

1. I want to fetch history of for last 10 for specific user. I tried
   query but it need both user_id and video_id in where clause.
2. I want to delete history by video_id

So main issue if fetching or deleting data with only one partition key which is not working and I can't find any solution.

I will really appreciate your help and I can use any other database which will fit better for this or any solution in this database.

Comment: What does "fetch history of for last 10 for specific user" mean?

Comment: What do you hope to gain by moving some data to Cassandra?

Comment: What is the question - backup speed?  deletion speed?  fetch syntax?

Comment: Hi @RickJames thanks for comments. I want to get last 10 watched videos for user by user id.

Comment: I'm moving data to make mysql database small and managing just history data separate. That will make easy for me to backup both easily.

Comment: You want (up to) 10 rows for each user?  That's a "groupwise max" problem; follow the tag I am adding.

Comment: @RickJames yes i want last 10 watched videos of user when they open there profile.

Comment: Ok, groupwise-max is not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ...
    FROM history
    WHERE user_id = ?
    ORDER BY history_timestamp DESC
    LIMIT 10
```

and add this to the table `history`:

```
INDEX(user_id, history_timestamp)
```

That probably needs a `JOIN` using `video_id` to some other table to get the names of the 10 videos.

(What is `history_counter` for?  The current state of someone viewing a video?  Something else?)

Comment: `history_counter` is number of time user watched video. I think you are giving me this for MYSQL but i want this for Cassandra. I'm already using MYSQL and want to shift this table to cassandra.